# Symfony inject parameter in repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need inject parameter in repository, I try add calls to service repo but my call function not call when I call some function from my repo

```
    app.repository.file:
    class:            "%app.repository.file.class%"
    factory_service:  doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method:   getRepository
    arguments:
        - "%app.entity.file.class%"
    calls:
         - [setParam,['%md5_suffix%']]
```

setParam not call

```
    private $param;

public function setParam($param)
{
    $this->param = $param;
}
```

param have `null`

and I try use JMSDiExtraBundle

```
    /**
 * @DI\InjectParams({
 *     "param" = @DI\Inject("%md5_suffix%"),
 * })
 */
public function setParam($param)
{
    $this->param = $param;
}
```

but have in property `%md5_suffix%` like string, not property from `parameters.yml` :)

how to inject parameter from parameters yml in repo ?

Comment: With your first try how are you trying to access the repository?  You need to pull it directly from the service container or inject it.  $entityManager->getRepository will not work.

Comment: `$entityManager->getRepository` exactly call like this and not work

Comment: $em->getRepo knows nothing about the symfony container.  From a controller you need something like $repo = $this->get('app.repository.file');

Answer (score 0):

Factory_service is deprecated in 2.8. Instead, try using something like:

```
app.repository.file:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', getRepository]
    arguments:
      - "%app.entity.file.class%"
    calls:
      - [setParam,['%md5_suffix%']]
```

Comment: just bear in mind you have to get your repo as a service now `$this->get('my_repo_alias')` or in this case `$this->get('app.repository.file')`

Answer (score -1):

I create another service

```
economy.param_helper:
    class: "%economy.param_helper.class%"
    arguments:
        - "%md5_suffix%"
```

and inject this service in repo like this

```
    /**
 * @var ParamHelper
 */
private $param;

    /**
 * @DI\InjectParams({
 *     "param" = @DI\Inject("economy.param_helper"),
 * })
 */
public function setParam(ParamHelper $param)
{
    $this->param = $param;
}
```

and call `$md5Suffix = $this->param->getMd5Suffix();`

But I'am not sure this is right way

Comment: This sort of stuff should be added to your original question unless it is actually an answer?

Comment: You can do it using a factory, see my answer

Comment: not work for me because calll like this ` 
$em->getRepo ` knows nothing about the symfony container

Comment: Cerad says about why not call setParam, and I agree with him and thnks him for that. Then I find out for my solution - create another service and inject in service parameters and inject this service in repo  - JMSDiExtraBundle. And now when ` $em->getRepo ` I have in repo another service with parameters what I need. You need attentively read conversation and question